# How to change website content based on kubernetes cluster location?

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, azure, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm going to run several Kubernetes Clusters in different public clouds and even on-prem ones (which will be in different locations). I'm gonna have the same HTML/javascript website running on all of them. I'd like to be able to change an image based on what cluster I am in. The image itself will display what cluster it's currently in eg: AWS, Azure, GCP, etc.

For instance, every time you refresh you end up in a different cluster and you can see which one because the image will be displayed.

I don't have a clue how to do this. So far I'm sure it'll require JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each cloud vendor usually has a metadata server. Google, AWS and Azure have metadata services that you can read configuration details from using HTTP.

To determine the cloud vendor on Linux read the Cloud Init Instance data. The JSON key `cloud-name` will tell you the cloud vendor.

Read this file and parse the JSON data:

```
/run/cloud-init/instance-data.json
```

Consult the documentation for each service, see the links below. Once you know which cloud you are running on, you can query for the region, cluster name, etc. Your server-side code can then display anything you want to clients.

AWS Endpoint:

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html)

Azure Endpoint:

```
http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2020-06-01
```

[Azure Documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-friday-azure-instance-metadata-service-jayaraman/)

Google Endpoint:

```
http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata
```

[Google Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata)

Answer (score 1):

- You can use Kubernetes JavaScript Client https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript to get Kubernetes Node Objects Information from inside your Kubernetes Pod using the Service Account associated to the Pod.
- Are you going to use AWS EKS, Azure AKS and GCP GKE for Cloud Kubernetes ? In that case, the Cloud Controller Manager https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/cloud-controller/ will annotate the Kubernetes Nodes with the relevant information
- How are you going to install and manage your On Prem Kubernetes ? Using OpenShift, Rancher or some other Middleware ?